# What webserver and programming language/database used for Stackoverflow

Tags: programming-languages

Wondering what technologies were used to create this web site?

Comment: a quick and simple internet search would answer this....

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/189582

Answer (score 2):

[See here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/). It is built in C# using ASP.NET MVC with a SQL Server 2008 database